# SPHINX : How to set the matchMode on the mysql client

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I installed Sphinx search on debian squeeze.

Connection trough the mysql client, with :

mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 9306 --protocol=tcp

gives me access to the searchd. I would like to change  the matching mode to

SPH_MATCH_ANY

I don't have any access to the php api (because it is not included into squeeze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your query to make it a quarum search. That's the benefit of extended match mode - it can emulate all the others

where match('"one two three"/1')

Can also use

option ranker=matchany